# Changing CSS depending on how much of the page is scrolled

Tags: jquery, scroll, scrolltop

I tried to do this on my own but I didn't get anywhere. All I have is:

```
if($("body").scrollTop() > 100) {
    $("header").css("display", "none");
}
```

It's within a document ready. What I want to do is add "display:none" to the `header` element when the page has scrolled 100px.

Learning jQuery slowly. Thank you.

Edit: The HTML is simply

```
<div id="wrap">
  <header>...</header>
  ...
</div>
```

`#wrap` is tall enough to need scrolling. When scrolling passed 100px I want to hide `header`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to hook onto the windows's `scroll` event and in there, check that object's `scrollTop()` value:

```
var $window = $(window),
    $header = $('header');

$window.scroll(function() {
    if ($window.scrollTop() > 100)
        $header.hide();
    else 
        $header.show();
});
```

Comment: This works! Thank you. Would you explaining what "hook onto the window's scroll event" means?

Comment: With the above `$(window).scroll(...)` call, your telling the browser (with jQuery) to call the given function everytime the window updates its scrolling position. It's basically firing 'scroll' events at every scroll updates, and you want your function to be called when that happens.

Answer (score -2):

$("header") it should be $("#header") where header is id of header div

Comment: I am not using an id for my header. I want to hide the <header> element that I am using.